# As a User, what to do if I find a question with an accepted answer but that does not work for me

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, accepted-answer

I could not find a similar question here in meta, if there is please point me to that.

My case is this:

I want to ask a question, I go on stackoverflow and I find that the question has already been asked and it has an accepted answer.
I tried it, but the answer (altough correct and good for many people) does not fix my problem.

The fact that the question has already an accepted answer prevent people to try to answer it again and the fact that is already there prevents me to ask it again and see it closed in 20 nanoseconds by the dup-busters.

What can I do?

Example: [Disable re-queue-ing of Failed Hangfire BackgroundJob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28849407/disable-re-queue-ing-of-failed-hangfire-backgroundjob)

If you see in a comment in the answer a guy have the same problem but the answer  is not working for him

Comment: When asking your question state clearly why the other question's answer does not work for you.

Comment: You mean I should ask a duplicate question?

Comment: But it won't be a duplicate since you'll be explaining clearly why it isn't.

Comment: You could also add a comment to the answer and explain there why it did not work for you. Maybe the answerer can enhance the answer to also incorporate your specific case

Comment: If the original question has significantly different answers test each of them, not just the accepted answer, and explain how each approach failed for your situation.

Comment: If you want to ask the same question as one that already exists and is accepted (and I assume the answer is highly upvoted) for which none of the answers actually work for you, then that is probably a hint that you're going to ask the wrong question. It may need to be made a whole lot more specific.

Comment: I added an example that it is actually what created my doubt

Comment: Rephrase. Your. Question.

Comment: @Mast No. I. Will. Not. ;)

Comment: I don't think you understand me. If the answer given does not solve your problem, your problem is different than the one considered a duplicate. However, it's phrased in such a way that it's considered a duplicate. To prevent being considered a duplicate, rephrase the question to make it different enough. Indicate why your problem is different. Give additional information. In other words, if your question is considered a duplicate, consider rephrasing your question.

Answer (score 8):

1. Try *all* of the answers, not just the accepted one.
2. Double check your scenario against the one described in the question. Are they identical?
3. Double check what you tried versus all of the prescribed answers. Did you miss a step or misunderstand a step?

If you are certain that you cannot resolve your problem with the information in the existing question you found...

1. If the question is fresh, you might be able to get help by leaving a comment.
2. Post a new question, but the new question shouldn't be a duplicate. You should link back to the old question, provide *more* details than the old question, and explain the results of trying all of those existing answers (why none work).

Comment: I added an example that it is actually what created my doubt

Comment: @MaurizioIndenmark the "example" you point to isn't that great of a question, nor does it have that great of an answer... But I don't see how you can't apply everything I've said exactly to this scenario. Assuming you've tried the answer, post a new question link to the example, state that you tried that and that didn't work, and try to add as much other detail as possible.

Comment: Well, it is all applicable to this scenario, and point 1 to 3 are actually things that should already happen before I even think of writing a new question.

Answer (score 4):

Ask your question. In your question, clearly explain why the answers in the related question don't work. This is critical. Without this explanation, you've asked a duplicate. Even with this information, if you are not clear you still may have asked a duplicate.

Show *why* the alternative didn't work. What results do you get versus what is expected? Do you get an error message? If so post that too. The details are important (just like in any question).

---

You may want to look at the "Related" questions list on the question that didn't work for you too. There are likely to be similar questions. Perhaps one of those will solve your problem. The non-accepted answers on any of the questions are another place to look for information. Just because the accepted answer of a question doesn't work for you, does not mean one of the others won't work.

If you find one of the non-accepted answers works for you, consider providing an upvote as well.

Comment: What if I get exactly the same error as the original question and I use exactly the same code and I have no idea why the answer he accepted is not working for me. This is very common for example when the answer is to change some configuration file thingy...

Comment: I added an example that it is actually what created my doubt

Answer (score -2):

I would say first comment on the accepted answer and state that the answer did not work. Wait for the reply. Now a couple of things could happen:

- The person who answered(or a different user) comes with a new solution and everythings fine.
- The person who answered doesn't reply. In this case I would start a new question. However I do think this wont be a complete duplicate. If it looks a lot like a duplicate, if I were you I would state that you have checked out several posts on SO (even put in the link) and say that it didn't work for you. State everything  that's different from the other question(On topic though).
- The person who answered doesn't know what to do next. In this case you could give the person who answered a little bit more information and maybe even get a clue in which direction the problem is. If this doesn't work I would do the same as if the person didn't reply.

Comment: Sure this is a great answer that take all cases into consideration. But implementing this means it could potentially take days to just ask a question on stack overflow and that will make it not worth for me to do so.

Comment: @MaurizioIndenmark it **should** take you days to ask a question. If you haven't invested at least this much time in solving the problem on your own, it is extraordinarily doubtful you've done enough research to actually ask a good question.

Comment: @nhgrif absolutely not. I invest days trying to solve my problem and if I solve it myself I do not give a shot about sharing it with others. Then if after days I cannt solve it I want to ask in stackoverflow and I want to do so as quickly and concise as possible